# Ejb deployment descriptor and annotations

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, ejb-3.0, deployment-descriptor

Say if have configuration in both deployment descriptor and annotations which one will be effective. Will annotations override the deployment descriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deployment Descriptors override Annotations.  Here is an excerpt from the Java EE Tutorial.

> Deployment information is most commonly specified in the source code by annotations. Deployment descriptors, if present, override what is specified in the source code.

[5.1 Packaging Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/packaging001.htm#BCGDJDFB)